# SSRS Chart. Displaying data in a different way than the dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

Perhaps someone can point me an online resourse that can give me hints on how to accomplish the following.

Scenario. I have a dataset that returns two columns.  NAME and AMOUNT.  See chart below.

1. Name-----------------------                   Amount 
   Approved------------------               0 
   Canceled------------------             20548010 
   Completed-----------------            160320000 
   Denied----------------------                 0 
   Draft------------------------                  0 
   Proposed------------------             35209000 
   Re-Approve---------------             0 
   Ready to Approve--------      3208000 
   Total------------------------                219285010
2. Currenty the pie chart shows all the Names/values. APPROVED, CANCELED, COMPLETED, DENIED, DRAFT, PROPOSED , RE-APPROVE, READY TO APPROVE as percentages of the total.

Here is what I would like to accomplish.

1. I would like to only show APPROVED, CANCELED, COMPLETED and DENIED.  I would like to group the others, DRAFT, PROPOSED, RE-APPROVE, and READY TO APPROVE in a separate group called "OTHER".
2. I then would like to show in the pie chart the Names/values , APPROVED, CANCELED, COMPLETED, DENIED and OTHER  as percentages of the total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know I'm late to the party, but here's another approach you could take.

1. Right-click on your dataset and choose `Add Calculated Field ...`
2. Add a field named `DisplayName` (we'll use this to perform your naming logic above), and set the expression to

   > ```
   > =IIf(Fields!Name.Value.Equals("Approved") OR 
   >    Fields!Name.Value.Equals("Canceled") OR 
   >    Fields!Name.Value.Equals("Completed") OR 
   >    Fields!Name.Value.Equals("Denied"), 
   >    Fields!Name.Value, "Other")
   > ```

   [image]
3. Setup your chart with the following base settings:

   [image]
4. Right-click on your pie chart and choose `Show Data Labels`
5. Right-click on one of the data labels and choose `Series Label Properties`
6. Add the following expression under `Label data`

   > =Fields!DisplayName.Value & " #PERCENT{P0}"
7. You may find that there's too much text on the Pie Chart if it's small.  You can set the `PieLabelSyle` CustomAttribute of the Pie Chart to `Outside` (you can find this by clicking on the Pie Chart and then examining the Properties window), which looks like this:

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with expressions in the pie chart.

You have a category group (or perhaps a series group) that groups by name. Edit that group and in the Group On write an expression that uses the Iif() function something like this:

=Iif(Fields!Name.Value = "APPROVED" Or Fields!Name.Value = "CANCELED" Or Fields!Name.Value = "COMPLETED" Or Fields!Name.Value = "DENIED", Fields!Name.Value, "OTHER")

Then edit the chart's [Value], go to the Point Labels tab. Check the SHow point labels box if it isn't already. Change the Data label expression to something like this:

=Sum(Fields!Amount.Value) / Sum(Fields!Amount.Value,"TheNameOfYourDatasetHere")

Then put 'p' in the Format Code box to show the value as a percentage.

NOTE: this is based on SSRS 2005. You have both 2005 and 2008 tags on the question, so I'm not certain which you're using. 2008 will be somewhat different but similar.